# replace in shell if next line consists of required string

Tags: shell

Using sed or any other unix command I need to replace "failure" string with "warning" in below scenario only if next line contains something like "time-out"

```
<failure>
    time-out of test exceeded allowable amount (5 secs)
</failure>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When posting an answer, please share your code, and try to explain your problem as best as you can. Right now, it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Show your code ... Make your question crisp and to the point

Comment: I'm new here and learning, now I hope the question is clear, thanks.

Comment: The question is nearly clear (you didn't say what shell you are going to use), but to discuss an issue, we need to see how far you already got by writing the program. You don't expect other people write the scripts for you, do you?

Comment: @darknight1906: You are basically doing a multi-line replace, and sed is, to the best of my knowledge, cumbersome to use in this case. Why not doing it in Ruby or Perl (or any other suitable language)? Also, what is the expected behaviour if the string is on the same line as the tag, i.e. `<failure>time-out .... </failure>`?

Comment: @user1934428: there isn't a scenario in our case where anything will precede <failure> in the same line, it will always be in the next line. I'm also trying few things, if anything works I will post here. Thanks.

Comment: instead of sed I used xmlstarlet and it worked like a charm, thanks everyone for taking time to reply.